# Read data from the appcache

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML5 application that works offline. As part of the solution I would like to use the appcache version as the product version. Is there anyway to read the comments (or any section) from the appcache file, in Javascript?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">  var versionnumber;  </script>`  Plus another 5,500 or so lines of unrelated code, but thats not important.

Comment: That's not much to go with... I will take a look

Comment: I am thinking of maybe importing the appcache file somehow, maybe using a script tag? Plus this will be happening on the main thread, I dont think "importScript" is available to me. Also as the file is part of the website and not uploaded by the, the HTML5 File APIs are of no use. Im having a fiddle around with an AJAX call but I am not sure if this will work offline.

Comment: What server side technology do you use? You could also read that file server side and return the value by calling a special page / handler.

Comment: I managed to achieve this using an AJAX GET request on the appcache file. I just need to test whether this request gets handled by the browser cache when the device is offline.

Comment: Or use the onerror in the AJAX GET to default it to a cached value (using localstorage or something like it).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve this by doing an AJAX GET on the file. If the app is offline, the GET is handled by the browser and it serves up the cached copy.